# Powershell - Displaying an XPS document in Document Viewer using WPF

Tags: wpf, powershell

I am trying to load a docx file in documentviewer using WPF (PowerShell). I figured that I can't do it for a docx file, so i am converting the docx file to XPS first. But I am not sure how to load the XPS document into DocumentViewer.

To load the document I probably need something like this, but I get an error:

```
New-Object : A constructor was not found. Cannot find an appropriate constructor for type System.Windows.Documents.IDocumentPaginatorSource.
```

XAML...

```
<DocumentViewer Name="docViewer" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>

$docViewer = $form.FindName('docViewer')
$docViewer.Document = New-Object System.Windows.Documents.IDocumentPaginatorSource('test.xps')
```

Comment: Please add the full error message to [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63621905/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Got it...

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName ReachFramework 
$docViewer.Document = (New-Object System.Windows.Documents.IDocumentPaginatorSource('test.xps', [System.IO.FileAccess]::Read)).GetFixedDocumentSequence()
```